# My bluetooth headphones stop reproducing sounds when I have Skype running

Tags: sound, bluetooth, skype, headphones

I am recently annoyed by a problem between my bluetooth headphones and Skype. I face this issue on my Kubuntu 20.04. The problem arises in the following way:

1. I connect my **bluetooth headphones** to the PC;
2. I run Skype and I start a call, with my headphones connected but I don't hear anything;
3. I close the call and I avoid using the headphones for the call (thus I talk through the default mic on my PC, and I hear from the PC speakers). Then I reconnect the headphones to listen to music, but headphones don't play anything;
4. I kill the skype process and I can hear again the sounds from my headphones;
5. if I then restart Skype I hear from the headphones until the next call. If I receive a call, I need to repeat the steps 3 and 4 to listen from my headphones again.

It looks as Skype breaks something whenever it tries to get access to the headphones, and I have no idea why since I just installed skype from the official repo, and setup the mic and the audio output to default (i.e. it should be synced with the one already in use by Ubuntu).
I also tried with *no-bluetooth headphones*, and the problem doesn't show up with them.

Did anybody have a similar experience. Do you have any solution that I can try to stop this annoying problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not exactly the same but I have something similar with Zoom and Teams. Especially after using Zoom, I end up having to restart pulseaudio and killing / restarting Teams in order to get my audio back.

Restart pulseaudio with

pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start

In your case I'd suggest installing pavucontrol which allows you to get granular about which apps use which audio devices.